# Consumer thread error, thread abort on SimpleMessageListenerContainer

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have a application that is running a few months but recently the application is throw a error during receipt message by mq.
When the error is throw the application don't consume more messages. Restarting the application the consume of message is running normaly.

> Erro:
>   4644201:[2018-10-02 10:34:31,068] ERROR [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1473) - Consumer thread error, thread abort.
>   4644418-java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/classify/SubclassClassifier$ClassComparator
>   4644514-    at org.springframework.classify.SubclassClassifier.classify(SubclassClassifier.java:115)
>   4644604-    at org.springframework.classify.BinaryExceptionClassifier.classify(BinaryExceptionClassifier.java:104)
>   4644708-    at org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy.retryForException(SimpleRetryPolicy.java:191)
>   4644809-    at org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy.canRetry(SimpleRetryPolicy.java:143)
>   4644901-    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.canRetry(RetryTemplate.java:357)
>   4644986-    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:291)
>   4645072-    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:172)
>   4645156-    at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:98)
>   4645268-    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   4645378-    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
>   4645471-    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.invokeListener(Unknown Source)
>   4645529-    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1238)
>   4645662-    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:727)
>   4645799-    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1192)
>   4645937-    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1176)
>   4646073-    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1100(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:99)
>   4646201-    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1370)
>   4646354-    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   4646396-Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.classify.SubclassClassifier$ClassComparator

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `spring-retry` on the class path. What are you using for dependency management? It should be added to the classpath automatically when using Maven or Gradle since it's a transitive dependency of `spring-amqp`.

> Restarting the application the consume of message is running normaly.

That makes no sense; unless you have some kind of weird classloader problem.

Try running with `-verbose` to get logs for all the class loading.